# Laravel: download a new excel file

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a bit confused, I'm using Laravel Excel to create reports, the thing is that I have a response via ajax, so the method `Excel::download` dont work, I've been googling and I found that i can save my excel file in my public folder and that also I can create the link with this `asset('file_name.txt')`, I got the link but when I pasted it it says that the page is not found, what am i missing?

My export method

```
 private function exportar($movimientos, $caso, $empresa, $producto, $linea, $seccion, $tipo)
{
    $nombre = 'inf_mov_' . Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y') . '.xlsx';
    Excel::store(new MovimientosExport($movimientos, $caso, $empresa, $producto, $linea, $seccion, $tipo), $nombre);
    return asset($nombre);
}
```

The file in the folder 
[image]

Link example: http://cdaf.test:81/inf_mov_14-03-2019.xlsx

Comment: That does not look like your `/public` folder. The public folder should contain an `index.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/store.html):

> By default the file will be stored inside the `storage/exports` folder, which has been defined in the `export.php` config file.

The `asset` helper generates URLs for files in the `public` folder, so you're linking to `public/file_name.txt`, which doesn't exist, as the file is at `storage/exports/file_name.txt` (a location that isn't available to the web browser, as only the `public` folder is).

Your best bet is to [set up your public storage folder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk), and have your Excel exports saved there.

Comment: U're right, i was pretty close, the file was already in the public folder but I was missing in the link this part http://cdaf.test:81/storage/inf_mov_14-03-2019.xlsx, I missed to get inside 'storage' folder hahah btw thx for the answer